# ScrollTo within a div on a page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to scroll down a page to load more content. Normally I would do the following:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

However, I have a page where it is only a left sidebar that needs to be scrolled, and doing something like the following does not work. See image here --

[image]

How would I scroll down the left sidebar? The xpath of the containing element is: `//li[contains(@class, "search-result")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

`var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;`

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to your approach, you can simply do

`document.getElementById(YOUR_HTML_DIV).scrollTop = SCROLL_VALUE_INT;`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zj0sk5tr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

So here we you are scrolling 'window' to 'document.body.scrollHeight'.

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

.scrollTo() and .scrollHeight are a method/property on HTML elements. Just need to do the same thing, but with the target div as the element instead of the window/document.body. Can get it with document.findById or jQuery etc.